# ¿Alguien sabe como mover imagenes con css?

Tags: html5, css3, angular10

Alguien tiene idea de como puedo hacer que se mueva una imagen de un sol en html, quiero que se mueva por la pantalla usando css y html, trato de hacer esto en un proyecto de angular 10.

El sol tiene que moverse de acuerdo al movimiento de un pequeño panel solar hecho en javaScript

les comparto el codigo del servidor de js que controla el seguidor

es todo lo que puedo decir, necesito que la imagen se mueva de acuerdo a lo que se mueva el panel.

```
`

const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const SocketIO = require('socket.io');
const five = require('johnny-five');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = SocketIO(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 3000!');
});

const board = new five.Board();

board.on('ready', function () {
  const servoHorizontal = new five.Servo({
    pin: 10
  });

  const servoVertical = new five.Servo({
    pin: 9
  });

  this.repl.inject({
    servoHorizontal
  });

  const ldrTopRight = new five.Sensor('A1');
  const ldrTopLeft = new five.Sensor('A2');
  const ldrBottomRight = new five.Sensor('A0');
  const ldrBottomLeft = new five.Sensor('A3');

  setInterval(function () {
    let topRightValue = ldrTopRight.value;
    let topLeftValue = ldrTopLeft.value;
    let bottomRightValue = ldrBottomRight.value;
    let bottomLeftValue = ldrBottomLeft.value;

    let gradosServoHorizontal = servoHorizontal.value;
    let gradosServoVertical = servoVertical.value;

    let avgTop = (topLeftValue + topRightValue) / 2;
    let avgRight = (topRightValue + bottomRightValue) / 2;
    let avgBottom = (bottomRightValue + bottomLeftValue) / 2;
    let avgLeft = (topLeftValue + bottomLeftValue) / 2;

    if (avgTop < avgBottom) {
      gradosServoVertical++;
      servoVertical.to(gradosServoVertical);
    } else if (avgTop > avgBottom) {
      gradosServoVertical--;
      servoVertical.to(gradosServoVertical);
    } else {
      servoVertical.to(gradosServoVertical);
    }

    if (avgLeft > avgRight) {
      gradosServoHorizontal++;
      servoHorizontal.to(gradosServoHorizontal);
    } else if (avgLeft < avgRight) {
      gradosServoHorizontal--;
      servoHorizontal.to(gradosServoHorizontal);
    } else {
      servoHorizontal.to(gradosServoHorizontal);
    }

    io.emit('rotaciones',`introducir el código aquí`introducir el código aquí`
      [gradosServoVertical, gradosServoHorizontal]);

  }, 1000);
});`
```

Comment: Hola que tal. Tal vez si añades un ejemplo en [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) podamos ayudarte.